# asking for a framework that allows to [cut]

Tags: discussion

I'm searching a framework that allows to... [cut]. I fear that such a question would be closed on stackexchange wordpress. Where can I ask it and hope to receive some useful answers? Thank you.

Comment: So yes this would be closed on the main site as a software recommendation

Comment: So, where can I do such a question?

Answer (score 2):

Recommendations are indeed considered to be not in scope here.

I think social media groups, such as [WordPress Developers at Google+](https://plus.google.com/communities/110928980572284315377), are typically recommended for questions that don't fit too well here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a stack in beta that looks appropriate, though I have not read through the stack's specific terms: softwarerecs.stackexchange.com